# Opening another window of powershell to run a ping command

Tags: powershell

I work for an ISP and I'm building a script that will put time, date, ping in that order into a saved file. That part works just fine, it operates as needed. What I am running into is I would like to have a script that opens a second window that either shows the results of the ping, or just puts the output into the same window, second ping could throw off the results, so that is not advisable. It could be as simple as I'm missing an output command, but that's why I'm here. Aside from the code I've shown, there is just a couple user prompts to ask users for ip address, name, and bytesize for the pings. If someone knows a way to change the file name so that it is named "james_PingTest" Or something along those lines, that would be a helpful addition.

```
Ping.exe -t /l $bytesize -f $ipaddr | ForEach {"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_}> $env:ProgramData/PingTests/pingtest.txt
```

Here is the relevant line of code. I have tried this command:

```
start powershell {Ping.exe -t /l $bytesize -f $ipaddr | ForEach {"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_}>}
```

Along with:

```
invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -Command { [Ping.exe -t /l $bytesize -f $ipaddr | ForEach {"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_}>] }'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe your output to the [`Tee-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.4) - it'll let you output to a file while preserving normal pipeline output:

```
ping.exe -t -l $bytesize -f $ipaddr |ForEach-Object { 
  (Get-Date),$_ -join ' - ' 
} |Tee-Object -FilePath $env:ProgramData/PingTests/pingtest.txt
```

Comment: That is perfect, do you know anything about changing the file/naming scheme so I can have multiple pings running at once?

Comment: For anyone else looking here is how I did it: `ping.exe -t -l $bytesize -f $ipaddr |ForEach-Object {(Get-Date),$_ -join ' - ' } |Tee-Object -FilePath $env:UserProfile\Desktop\pingtest.txt`